Winter Bash 2012 Preparations


Last year, on our Gaming site, we hosted an event called Hat Dash,
  where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain
  tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user
  receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". 
For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora
  with pen) to the editor. 
This year, we're expanding the promotion to all sites which choose to participate, and redesigning the hat selection to be more
  appropriate to the entire network (no severed Wampa heads). Some of
  it is holiday-themed, some of it is a bit silly, and all of it is
  (hopefully) fun!
This event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013. Users
  will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh.
  That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and
  other details of the event. 
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
  hats, and/or are generally  anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option
  available, just as we had on Gaming last year. 
The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the
  hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.
All responses will need to be in by 28 November 2012. Sites that
  haven’t responded by then will be considered to have "opted out" from
  the event.


I like hats. Do we get to choose which one we would wear from the several that will be earned?

Yes, you do. People, please do wear your hats :-)

I like the idea of the competition. I think it suites the playful nature of LEGO bricks but I worry the sites community may be too small to benefit.

I don't think we're too small - and it might help spread the word among the network ;)

Especially if we can get LEGO-themed hats, which I think we should ask for

So is that a unanimous yes then? ;)

@Zhaph-BenDuguid From the moderators only, it looks like it's a yes.

And on the other hand, there doesn't seem to be any "no" anyway, so I'd say, let's treat it as a "yes", and if people complain later it'll be a good opportunity to tell them to read meta too.
